# SQL Server 2008: Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I wrote a stored procedure to use one of my DLLs inside SQL Server 2008.

```
create proc stpMine
as
EXTERNAL NAME MyDll.[MyDll.ClassName].[StaticMethod]
```

This library uses Entity Framework and Json.Net. When I try to run the stored procedure, it gives me the following error:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "stpMine":
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
>
>   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.<GenerateStatements>b__2(Object o)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.GenerateStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations)
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>   at System.D...

Can anyone guide me about fixing this error? If you're sure that this is because of EF, I can rewrite my context to directly use ADO.NET, but I prefer to keep it untouched.

Comment: If it works after running ALTER DATABASE X SET TRUSTWORTHY ON then it's a code access policy issue. Not sure if leaving the database trustworthy is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks Wonko, our original script that has been used to create this stored procedure contains `Alter Database Master set trustworthy on`.

Comment: I think you have to set trustworthy for the database in which the assembly is part.

Comment: You mean the entire database, and not just the table? It's not possible in my case, thanks though.